# Image location doesn't work if your page is Landscape in migradoc (pdfsharp)

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

i have the following code that works fine to put an image in the bottom left of the page (in portrait mode).  once i change the page to landscape mode, the image goes off the screen.

how would i lay this out in landscape mode so it shows up on the bottom left of the screen.  here is the code:

```
   Section section = document.AddSection();

  Image image2 = section.AddImage("../../back.png");
  image2.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Page;
  image2.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;
  image2.Left = ShapePosition.Left;
    image2.Top = ShapePosition.Bottom;
  image2.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;
```

if i change:

```
    image2.Top = ShapePosition.Bottom;
```

to

```
    image2.Top = ShapePosition.Top;
```

it shows up fine on the top left, but doesn't work on the bottom left.  I can work around this by having

```
image2.Top = 550
```

but i would have thought ShapePosition.Bottom would work in landscape mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug.

I've put it on our error list, but I don't have time now to investigate it.

Good for you that you found a workaround.